# An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@tsnpm/uikit/-/uikit-0.7.26.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I've been trying to do `yarn install` and `yarn` to a project from work but for some reason it keeps displaying the same message and I can't delete the @tspnm/uikit because it's being used in many places.

The node version is 15.13.0

yarn version 1.22.5

and npm version 7.7.6.

I've tried doing `yarn cache clean` and then `yarn` and still the same, I've also tried deleting the `yarn.lock` file and got the same result.

[image: The message after running yarn or yarn install]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the legacy react-native-cli

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

Install new one from "react-native-community":

npm i -g @react-native-community/cli

after that, init the Project with:

npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript